# Is there a way to resolve this error in using gmaps

Tags: python-3.10

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
def _customer_plot(_df):

    _customer_locations = []
    for i in range(1, len(_df)):
        _customer_locations.append((_df['lat'].iloc[i], _df['long'].iloc[i]))

    _fig = gmaps.figure()
    _pins= gmaps.marker_layer(_customer_locations)
    _fig.add_layer(_pins)

    _depot_location = []

    for i in range(0, 1):
      _depot_location.append((_df['lat'].iloc[0], _df['long'].iloc[0]))
    _depot = gmaps.symbol_layer(_depot_location, fill_color='blue', scale=6)
    _fig.add_layer(depot)

    return _fig

customer_plt = _customer_plot(df)
customer_plt



AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-36-6605bc6ffd10> in <cell line: 21>()
     19     return _fig
     20 
---> 21 customer_plt = _customer_plot(df)
     22 customer_plt

3 frames

<ipython-input-36-6605bc6ffd10> in _customer_plot(_df)
      7 
      8     _fig = gmaps.figure()
----> 9     _pins= gmaps.marker_layer(_customer_locations)
     10     _fig.add_layer(_pins)
     11 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gmaps/marker.py in marker_layer(locations, hover_text, label, info_box_content, display_info_box)
    551         A :class:`gmaps.Markers` instance.
    552     """
--> 553     marker_options = _marker_layers(
    554         locations, hover_text, label, info_box_content, display_info_box)
    555     markers = [Marker(**option) for option in marker_options]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gmaps/marker.py in _marker_layer_options(locations, hover_text, label, info_box_content, display_info_box)
    309     if is_atomic(label):
    310         label = [label] * number_markers
--> 311     if is_atomic(info_box_content):
    312         info_box_content = [info_box_content] * number_markers
    313 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gmaps/options.py in is_atomic(elem)
     38     return (
     39         isinstance(elem, string_types) or
---> 40         not isinstance(elem, collections.Iterable)
     41     )
     42 

AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'
```